# Error creating bean with name 'integrationGlobalProperties' after updated spring boot from 2.4.1 to 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im trying to run this Spring Boot project. Im trying to upgrade spring boot from version 2.4.1 to 2.7.0. I get those errors that you can see in the error stacktrace. Everything is working fine in version 2.4.1. Im using Intellij 2020.3 and also get the same errors running with maven.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
      </parent>
      <groupId>com.ms.md</groupId>
      <artifactId>app</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <name>proxyapp</name>
      <description>application</description>
    
      <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
      </properties>
    
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
          <version>5.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
          <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.5</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
          <version>7.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
          <version>8.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>1.18.22</version>
          <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
          <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    
    </project>
```

Error stacktrace

```
2022-06-03 10:39:52.667  INFO 15667 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
    2022-06-03 10:39:52.674  INFO 15667 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
    2022-06-03 10:39:52.748  INFO 15667 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2022-06-03 10:39:52.814  INFO 15667 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2022-06-03 10:39:52.816  INFO 15667 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2022-06-03 10:39:53.040  INFO 15667 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2022-06-03 10:39:53.046  INFO 15667 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2022-06-03 10:39:53.046  INFO 15667 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
    2022-06-03 10:39:53.148  INFO 15667 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2022-06-03 10:39:53.148  INFO 15667 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1744 ms
    2022-06-03 10:39:53.319  INFO 15667 --- [           main] c.m.a.s.a.a.AADAuthenticationProperties  : Creating AzureADStatelessAuthFilter bean.
    2022-06-03 10:39:53.944  INFO 15667 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@24aedcc5, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@74ebd159, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@37ffe4f3, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@785a4557, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@78eafad, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4751cd3, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@7dd3981e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@202f054f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@13908f9c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1850f2da, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3739f3c9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3ef0e576, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@8851ec]
    2022-06-03 10:39:55.291  WARN 15667 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'channelInitializer': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationGlobalProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/integration/IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties]: Factory method 'integrationGlobalProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.<init>()' (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    2022-06-03 10:39:55.295  INFO 15667 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2022-06-03 10:39:55.317  INFO 15667 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
    
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2022-06-03 10:39:55.334 ERROR 15667 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'channelInitializer': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationGlobalProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/integration/IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties]: Factory method 'integrationGlobalProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.<init>()' (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at com.equinor.mss.mdm.MdmProxyAppApplication.main(MdmProxyAppApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationGlobalProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/integration/IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties]: Factory method 'integrationGlobalProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.<init>()' (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1631) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.doEvaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:280) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:252) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationGlobalProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/integration/IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties]: Factory method 'integrationGlobalProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.<init>()' (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationContextUtils.getBeanOfType(IntegrationContextUtils.java:173) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationContextUtils.getIntegrationProperties(IntegrationContextUtils.java:195) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:139) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:139) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:95) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:61) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:273) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:167) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties]: Factory method 'integrationGlobalProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.<init>()' (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.<init>()' (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration.integrationGlobalProperties(IntegrationAutoConfiguration.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 46 common frames omitted
    
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issues by upgrading:

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
>   <version>5.5.12</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
>   <version>5.7.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```